# How do you "Share via" email & wifi option from gallery ? It's missing

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, email, gallery, share-menu

I recently upgraded to ICS (4.1.2) and have lost the ability to share photos from the gallery via email and wifi. The option was there before the upgrade. But not now. Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some mucking around, I discovered Google (un-intuitively) changed the way you can share photos in the gallery for email and wifi. You now need to do this

Open Gallery > Select Menu button > select "Select Items" > select the share button at the top of screen. All the icons should appear now in the share dialog window.